# java.sql.SQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, jdbc, rubymine

Developing RoR app on Windows using RubyMine, trying to connect to Postgres database hosted on Heroku server.  No Postgres installed locally.  Getting "java.sql.SQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host..."  What to do, what to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like this is a RubyMine issue.  RubyMine will convert the hostname to an IP address and pg_hba.conf includes the hostname but not the IP address hence the error.  It works fine from the command line (e.g. rails s).

Comment: Getting this as well - any way to fix this rather than use the console?

Comment: No, and I haven't checked if this is a known bug for RubyMine.

Answer (score 18):

This is due to Heroku databases needing additional SSL configuration.
You need to enable SSL in your jdbc string by appending:

```
?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

For details see [Heroku's help document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#connecting-to-a-database-remotely).